# Rails caching with memcached, get not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, memcached

I have come into an existing Rails project which claims to use memcached.  As a test I tried putting an object in the cache with

```
Rails.cache.write("gateway", @gateway)
```

Then retrieving it with

```
 Rails.cache.read("gateway", @gateway)
```

however this returns nil, why is this?

This is in a development environment, memcached is installed and running and should be enabled by the entries  config.cache_classes = true and config.action_controller.perform_caching = true.

Comment: Are you seeing this in production or dev/test environment?  It is fairly common for dev/test environments to turn caching off to catch code changes - see [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-nullstore).

Comment: +1 for useful suggestion

Comment: You could check what kind of cache is used by checking what class Rails.cache is

Answer (score 3):

Rails projects use memcached in various different ways but if you are working on a rails 3 project then I would suggest they may be using the **'dalli' gem** which uses a **memcached session store**. So using the cache could instead be done something like this `session[:gateway] = @gateway` and the opposite `@gateway = session[:gateway]` the other way it is done is `memcache.set('gateway',@gateway')` and `memcache.get('gateway')`

Would be helpful to see the **configuration code**. check `/config/initializers/session_store.rb` for something like `Rails.application.config.session_store :dalli_store ............`

Also as said in the comments if you are in **development caching may be turned off**. Check your `config/development.rb` file for the following:
`config.action_controller.perform_caching             = false`

the other thing is you need to have **memcached installed on your os** for linux this is `sudo apt-get install memcached` and can be checked by `ps aux | grep memcache` (this should show two proccesses the grep and memcache)

**Update**

Should also check out the [rails caching guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html)

Comment: Thanks for the good feedback.  Memcached is definitely installed and running; I'm trying to get this running in the development environment, I compared the production and dev. configs. and set caching to true for the dev. config. wherever I saw it.  Cache read is still returning nil.  If I go with a memcached session store is the 4KB size limit not in place?  I'll need to store more than that.

Comment: Did you try the alternate ways of reading and writing?, The size limit  for memcached is 1mb although this can be Overridden (this will throw a warning - `#WARNING: Setting item max size above 1MB is not recommended! 
#Raising this limit increases the minimum memory requirements, and 
will decrease your memory efficiency.` You may also want to look at compressing what you are storing

Comment: I use Rails.cache.write for my write and have tried Rails.cache.read and Rails.cache.fetch, no difference.  I do a read back right after I've written and the initial write is successful (i.e. reads back the right data), but then in the handoff to the next controller the read comes back as nil.  I've looked at all the settings you mentioned above and caching is turned on for dev. and production environments.  If I can't get this caching to work can you suggest another method to hand data between controller calls?

Comment: Would help if you can tell me the configuration code for your app so i can see where it is being stored.